# BEA-160228 LoggerFactory Logback LoggerContext. Either remove Logback... Weblogic springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, weblogic

I really lost the way here, i'm trying to deploy a springboot application, when I try to upload .war file in a weblogic 12c returns BEA-160228 with error message in title here is my pom.xml:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/CPernillo/6eg5oe

I've tried a lot of solutions that I found on forums even here in stack but nothing seems to work for me like disable spring-boot-starter-logging (as you can see in pom.xml), add a weblogic.xml to my webapp/WEB-INF folder (here it is):

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/CPernillo/yed5oA

Please stack-experts, help me and thanks in advance.

**Update 1**
This project has sucessfully deployed in a dev server, without changing anything, the problem is production server.

Comment: you can check my this question I had the same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095111/not-able-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-applicationnon-web-war-file-on-weblogic-12c/51173077#51173077

Comment: Spring Boot 2 doesn't support log4j. It supports log4j2 however. You should have preferences for SLF4j as well as logback for your regular classes.

Comment: thanks @ShubhamChopra but i don't use that annotation in my project

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, following your comment i've changed mi pom.xml and added dependendencies like this:
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/CPernillo/peg5pr
Changed my log4j.properties to this preferences:
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/CPernillo/8eGb8o
Still same error message (I forgot to tell this project is succesfully deployed in a out-of-box weblogic that is dev for me, but in production server got this message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed!**

---

I Answer only if in future somebody have to pass this bad luck:

Java versions in both weblogic where diferent, spring 2.0.3.REALEASE only supports java 8, so, production server has jdk 7, client's sysadmins gonna have a long night migrating all old projects to jdk 8.